# Toshiba Laptop blue screening

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod, toshiba-laptop

we have lot of laptop Toshiba which are blue screening.

I have rebuild the laptop, re-install GC drivers and remove wifi and netwrok drivers but still i keep getting blue screen on these laptops. the logs say somthing about GC drivers but its not that its the network card which is causing this. does anyone know the kb number which i can apply to make these laptop stop blue screening. 
its happening on Windows 7 x64 Toshiba laptops.

We had same problem with HP(r840) laptop but after applying Windows6.1-KB2664888-x64 and Windows6.1-KB2665206-x64. We haven't had this problem on HP laptops.

Answer (score 0):

Have you diagnosed the hard drive at all? Have you tried a fresh install of Windows on any of the units blue screening? Also is there a pattern with the blue screens either on boot up, loading windows, playing music etc? Are the laptops that are bluescreening on the internet? One last question is that does it blue screen in safe mode? let us know,

Thanks

Comment: These are brand new laptops. I have install fresh copy of OS. I think its caused by VPN software checkpoint.